# Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of primefaces theme library

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, themes

I use `primefaces-5.1.jar and`javax.faces-2.2.0.jar`(i got some error for`javax.faces-2.2.9.jar`)

Put this also in `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>#{Helper.theme}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

then i got error:

```
Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-bootstrap" library

javax.faces.FacesException: Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-bootstrap" library
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeTheme(HeadRenderer.java:134) ~[primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeBegin(HeadRenderer.java:81) ~[primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:869) ~[javax.faces-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854) ~[javax.faces-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) ~[javax.faces-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443) ~[javax.faces-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131) ~[javax.faces-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) ~[javax.faces-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) ~[javax.faces-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) ~[javax.faces-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) ~[javax.faces-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
```

But when i use `javax.faces-2.1.25.jar` the error above is solved but get another error:

```
com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash getCurrentFlashManager
SEVERE: JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming cookie value Invalid characters in decrypted value.  Processing will continue, but the flash is unavailable for this request.
```

My question is what compatible library for `primefaces-5.1.jar` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Put Primefaces Theme Maven dependecy into your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.8</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Official documentation suggests use the 10.0.10 version of Primefaces themes, requesting add their own repository, which is not working properly and I was still receiving an error and this version of themes is not available in the Maven Central Repository.

After much research without an effective solution, I had need to opt to the last version of Maven repository whose is available only up to version 1.0.8. but my project still getting the following warning:

> **WARNING: JSF1064:** Unable to find or serve resource, images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_70_000000_1x100.png, from library,
> primefaces-bootstrap.
>
> **WARNING: JSF1064:** Não foi possível encontrar ou fornecer o recurso, images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_70_000000_1x100.png, pela
> biblioteca, primefaces-bootstrap.

Thinking a little bit I found a simple solution that solves the bootstrap theme problem.

The solution is :

- Pass a new path to the image that is missed
- Replace the property `background` of **ui-widget-shadow** css class

Steps:

1. Download missed image : | [Link 1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Z-Wave-Me/z-way-mini-ui/master/css/images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_70_000000_1x100.png)    |    [Link 2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/codeorigin.jquery.com/master/cdn/ui/1.11.2/themes/cupertino/images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_70_000000_1x100.png) |    [Link 3](https://www.fulig.com.br/en/wp-content/plugins/wp_w2_contact_form/css/ui/cupertino/images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_70_000000_1x100.png) |

- All links refer to: **ui-bg_highlight-hard_70_000000_1x100.png**

2. Place this image in a folder of your project (Suggestion: `/resources/images/`)
3. Overwrite only the property that has the invalid reference to the image

Use the following code:

```
.ui-widget-shadow {
   background-image: url("images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_70_000000_1x100.png.jsf") !important;
}
```

That problem is discussed in:

- https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=19250&start=10

Answer (score 2):

Add dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
    <artifactId>cupertino</artifactId>  
    <version>1.0.8</version>  
</dependency>
```

Add configuration to web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>#{LayoutBean.applicationTheme}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Create an application scoped eager bean to load when the JSF application loads

```
@ManagedBean(name = "LayoutBean", eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class LayoutBean {

    private String theme = "cupertino";

    public String getApplicationTheme() {
        return theme;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that the dependency is well added in pom.xml (Add manually jar to maven local repository if this is premium theme, more info [here](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=42691))

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>{theme-name-here}</artifactId>
    <version>{version-here}</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Add the correct configuration in web.xml for use this theme.

  ```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>#{theme-name-here}</param-value>
  </context-param>
  ```

I had a case where everything was set up correctly but the message "Error loading theme, cannot find “theme.css” resource of primefaces theme library" still appeared. I solved it:

- Project in Eclipse --> clean... --> Clean all projects
- Right click in project --> refresh
- Go to servers view --> right click in Tomcat installation --> Clean and Publish
- Run app.

This remove all cache files, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

All recent versions of themes in the primefaces maven repository are compatible with 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you include only the primefaces jar or the themes as well? E.g. using maven you need a dependency for primefaces and a dependency for the theme or all themes. I forgot the latter and got the same exception. Have a look here (scroll down to "Installation"): [Primefaces/Themes](http://www.primefaces.org/themes)

Comment: So you mean you actually just did not install the theme

Comment: @Kukeltje No, I suggest to install the themes e.g. by writing a dependency into the maven pom.xml if she is using maven. Just saying in web.xml she wants to load it is not enough, it has to be there in the first place.